# Remap redo to C-S-/

Tags: undo, mapping

I do not like the standard keybinding to redo so I would like to customise it.
How can I remap redo to C-S-/?
I am not able to find any solution in internet.

Comment: Why not ask emacs how to do it ? Press `C-h-f` RET `global-set-key` RET

Comment: See the links for [this google search for "emacs map keys"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=emacs+map+keys) for instructions on how to bind keys (the manual, FAQs, tutorials, etc.).

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan Emacs doesn't have a `redo` as a separate command, so that's not quite enough...

Comment: @npostavs Oh yes, after using undo-tree for so long, I forgot about the default behaviour of emacs.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already try [undo-tree.el](http://www.dr-qubit.org/undo-tree/undo-tree.el).  It gives Emacs a conventional undo, otherwise you need to undo the undos in order to redo--there is no redo function...  With it you can add:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-/") 'undo-tree-redo)
```

to your emacs init file, or where ever you keep custom keybindings, and walk back and forward through any change.

Comment: By the way, `undo-tree-redo` is bound to to `C-/` by default, which is already equivalent to `C-S-?` (at least on American keyboard layouts).

Comment: That's why I assume the question is more about how to get a conventional undo and redo...

Answer (score 1):

By default, Emacs doesn't support redo with a single key-stroke.

You can do one of the following.

- Press `C-g`, `C-_`
- Write some [elisp to perform both actions for you](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54142/2418).
- This functionality has been made into a package called [undo-fu](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-undo-fu).
- Use undo-tree or redo+, however both have long-standing bugs, so I wouldn't recommend this, see:

  - https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9903
  - http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_best_redo_mode.html
  - https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/85t95p/undo_tree_unrecognized_entry_in_undo_list/