# Possible to use emacs-undo/redo without keyboard-quit? (Ctrl-G)

Tags: undo

Having run into a [bug with undo-tree](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9903), I'd rather use emacs default undo.

Mapping undo to `undo-only` and redo to `undo`.

This requires pressing `Ctrl-G` then `undo` to effectively redo an operation.

Is there a way to make the `Ctrl-G` implicit, so I don't need to press it in cases I've just used `undo-only`?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but since you expressly mentioned a problem with the `undo-tree` library relating to the canary bug, the following snippet should fix the canary error:  `(setq undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region nil)`

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but still get the bug occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

Note, this is now available as a package [undo-fu](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-undo-fu) which also provides improved redo support.

---

Yes, it is possible. You need to write a wrapper.

- For redo that sets the `last-command` to `ignore`.
- The `last-command` is set to undo because `undo` internal logic checks for this.
- `condition-case` is used so failing to undo doesn't prevent `this-command` from being set.

```el
(defun simple-redo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((last-command
         (cond
          ;; Break undo chain, avoid having to press Ctrl-G.
          ((string= last-command 'simple-undo) 'ignore)
          ;; Emacs undo uses this to detect successive undo calls.
          ((string= last-command 'simple-redo) 'undo)
          (t last-command))))
    (condition-case err
        (progn
          (undo) t)
      (error
       (message "%s" (error-message-string err)))))
  (setq this-command 'simple-redo))

(defun simple-undo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((last-command
         (cond
          ;; Emacs undo uses this to detect successive undo calls.
          ((string= last-command 'simple-undo) 'undo)
          ((string= last-command 'simple-redo) 'undo)
          (t last-command))))
    (condition-case err
        (progn
          (undo-only) t)
      (error
       (message "%s" (error-message-string err)))))
  (setq this-command 'simple-undo))
```

---

*Note that I've been using this for some months now and find it a surprisingly good alternative to more complex undo wrappers which were never entirely stable for me.*